# How to check OCMock release version?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

How to check OCMock release version? I want to know whether the code I am working on has the latest (release 2.1) OCMock. How to check that in xcode project?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the version doesn't appear anywhere in the distribution itself.

The best you can do is compare libOCMock.a to the current version, though if they built OCMock from source, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
otool -av /path/to/libOCMock.a
```

returns the compile date of all of the archive members, which gives a pretty good clue of which version it is.